# Excel File not opening in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, iis-6

I cant able to open the Excel,when i add my web application to IIS.
Even i gave  All rights to folder(in dcomcnfg).
Also almost i tried all thing,which given in google.
But it working in localhost.

```
string excelPath = Convert.ToString(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        try
        {
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@excelPath, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
            xlApp.Visible = true;
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
            xlWorkBook.Activate();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblPath.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
```

If i choose file from C drive,it showing error like->
'C:\Users\vino\Desktop\sample.xlsx' could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct. If you are trying to open the file from your list of most recently used files, make sure that the file has not been renamed, moved, or deleted.

If i choose file from D drive, completed succusfully, but Excel not opening.

i need to give any specific(imp) permission to folder?

Comment: Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct

Comment: Are you using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`? If so you should have Excel installed on your computer, so it works fine. But if there is no installation of Excel on the server (which I do not expect to be installed) it won't work.

Comment: Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel only. Also Excel installed on both local & server.

Comment: i need  to give any specific(imp) permission to folder?

Comment: If i choose excel file from D drive, completed succusfully, but Excel not opening,even in Task Manager Also.

Comment: shouldn't that be: `Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();` ?

Comment: if i like this mean, it shown error ->  Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).